# glMaterialfv not working for me

Tags: opengl-es

This is OpenGL on iPhone 4.

Im drawing scene using light and materials. Here is snippet of my code:
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustumf(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);

```
CGFloat ambientLight[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
CGFloat diffuseLight[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
CGFloat direction[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f, 0 };

glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, direction);


glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

float blankColor[4] = {0,0,0,1};
float whiteColor[4] = {1,1,1,1};
float blueColor[4] = {0,0,1,1};

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, blueColor);

glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts.pdata);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals.pdata);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, verts.size/3);
```

Problem is that instead of seeing BLUE diffuse color I see it white. It fades out if I rotate model's side but I can't understand why its not using my blue color.

BTW if I change glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, blueColor) to glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, blueColor) then I do see blue color. If I do it glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, blueColor); and then glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, blueColor); I see white color again. So it looks like GL_FRONT_AND_BACK shows it but rest of combinations show white. Anyone can explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of clockwise

> 10.090 How does face culling work? Why doesn't it use the surface normal?
>
> OpenGL face culling calculates the signed area of the filled primitive in window coordinate space. The signed area is positive when the window coordinates are in a counter-clockwise order and negative when clockwise. An app can use glFrontFace() to specify the ordering, counter-clockwise or clockwise, to be interpreted as a front-facing or back-facing primitive. An application can specify culling either front or back faces by calling glCullFace(). Finally, face culling must be enabled with a call to glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); .
>
> OpenGL uses your primitive's window space projection to determine face culling for two reasons. To create interesting lighting effects, it's often desirable to specify normals that aren't orthogonal to the surface being approximated. If these normals were used for face culling, it might cause some primitives to be culled erroneously. Also, a dot-product culling scheme could require a matrix inversion, which isn't always possible (i.e., in the case where the matrix is singular), whereas the signed area in DC space is always defined.
>
> However, some OpenGL implementations support the GL_EXT_ cull_vertex extension. If this extension is present, an application may specify a homogeneous eye position in object space. Vertices are flagged as culled, based on the dot product of the current normal with a vector from the vertex to the eye. If all vertices of a primitive are culled, the primitive isn't rendered. In many circumstances, using this extension

from [here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/clipping.htm)

Also you can read [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml)

Comment: As you see in my code I specify culling glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE). If my triangle was wrong direction wouldn't it be invisible? In any case I made 2 triangles. One CCW and one CW order. No matter what culling I use: GL_CW or GL_CCW in glFrontFace I always see one of 2 triangles (since they opposite direction) but always white color.

Comment: May be it depends on lighting? for example, strong light. try to change the angle between light direction and area of triangle?

Comment: If that be case then FRONT or FRONT_AND_BACK would have same results - white light. Anyhow I tried weaker light and it didnt help. Il scan though my code. Maybe I set somewhere some parameter in OGL that breaks it up. Thanks for help tho.

Comment: BTW one big detail I forgot. Its OpenGL on iPhone. Dont know if that make any difference.

Comment: if possible try toplace 2 triangle on angle /\ like a roof to the sun. sorry for bad english :-)

Comment: also change the value of diffuse light to the something like {0.2,0.2,0.2}

Comment: Finally found what was the problem. When loading model, I was normalizing it (fitting into box of 1x1x1) and thus I was setting model matrix with scaling. As result of scale, it affected normals and  since in most cases I was scaling down it made all models look supper bright. Now all is good. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to hear that you've solved your problem :-)